# Traverse binary tree - no recursion, no stack, no tree modification

Tags: data-structures, graph, tree, binary-search-tree, traversal

So for an application I am building I need to be able to traverse a binary tree without using recursion,  stack or modifying the tree in any way after it's been created. My node struct is as follows:

```
typedef struct 
{
    ValueType value;  //Data stored in node
    int left_index;   //Left child
    int right_index;  //Right child
    int parent_index; //Parent node
}
```

I am storing my tree as a 1D array where the left child of each node is at index 2*i + 1, the right child is at 2*i + 2 and the parent is at [i-1]/2. If a node doesn't have a parent or child, it's associated index is -1.

The only iterative non-stack based algorithm I found was something called "Morris Traversal" as seen here: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inorder-tree-traversal-without-recursion-and-without-stack/

However Morris Traversal modifies the tree during the traversal which I cannot do.

**I am willing to add whatever information is needed to each node just as long as I can write the algorithm given the above constraints.**

Is what I'm asking for even possible? And if so, how would I go about doing it? Not really sure how to even begin.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't a "while(!done)" loop be suffcient?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a [threaded binary tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threaded_binary_tree). The right pointer of all leaf nodes points to the node's in-order successor.

It's easy to create such a thing, and not difficult at all to update it when you insert or delete a node. If you have control of the node structure, then this is almost certainly what you want.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class TreeNode {
    int val;
    TreeNode left;
    TreeNode right;
    TreeNode parent;

    public void traverse() {
        TreeNode current = this.leftMost();
        while (current != null) {
            System.out.println("Current at " + current.val);
            current = current.inOrderNext();
        }
    }

    public TreeNode inOrderNext() {
        if (right != null) {
            return right.leftMost();
        } else {
            TreeNode current = this;
            TreeNode above = this.parent;
            while (true) {
                if (above == null) {
                    return null;
                } else {
                    if (above.left == current) {
                        return above;
                    } else {
                        current = above;
                        above = above.parent;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public TreeNode leftMost() {
        TreeNode result = this;
        while (result.left != null) {
            result = result.left;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        TreeNode first = new TreeNode();
        first.val = 4;

        TreeNode second = new TreeNode();
        second.val = 2;
        second.parent = first;
        first.left = second;

        TreeNode third = new TreeNode();
        third.val = 1;
        third.parent = second;
        second.left = third;

        third = new TreeNode();
        third.val = 3;
        third.parent = second;
        second.right = third;

        second = new TreeNode();
        second.val = 6;
        second.parent = first;
        first.right = second;

        third = new TreeNode();
        third.val = 5;
        third.parent = second;
        second.left = third;

        third = new TreeNode();
        third.val = 7;
        third.parent = second;
        second.right = third;

        first.traverse();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a lot of research on traversing a tree without "extras".  But the first extra people remove is the "parent" pointer.  With it, one can roam on a tree anyway he wants and makes everything easy.